# how to test asp.net web application on local host multiple browser

Tags: testing, cross-browser

I am developing a website in which for every change (ahhh.. I hate HTML and CSS) I need to check that it's working for all major browser.

Can you suggest me any tool/Software/Method to test like this.

**p.s.**:*My web app is not deployed, it's in development stage*

Just to inform you, I am using ASP.NET. (I afraid to put ASP.NET in my Tag, as it may not create interest for people from different web technology to answer my question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [Browserstack.com](http://Browserstack.com)  awesome plans to test cross browser...will even test localhost.